# Calculating totals in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Table a and Table b.

Table a is set up like...

Users

```
Id  ...  InspectStat    PurchaseStat    SoldStat    POSStat
------------------------------------------------------------
 1        
 2
 3
```

Properties

```
UserId  ...  Stage  
---------------------------------------------------    
    1        Inspect 
    3        Purchase
    1        Sold
    2        POS
```

I am trying to write a Job that will every hour, calculate the percentage of each users total properties in each stage. so for example, the end result should look like this (assuming that there are only these 4 properties)

```
Id  ...  InspectStat    PurchaseStat    SoldStat    POSStat
------------------------------------------------------------
 1           .5               0             .5         0
 2            0               0              0         1.0
 3            0               1.0            0         0
```

I have tried

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StatCounter]

AS
DECLARE @PropertyCount as float 

BEGIN

set @PropertyCount = (select count(AcquisitionAssociateId) from [dbo].[Properties],     [dbo].[Users]
WHERE
    [dbo].[Users].Id = [dbo].[Properties].AcquisitionAssociateId) 
update [dbo].[Users]
set [dbo].[Users].PurchaseStat = ((select count (AcquisitionAssociateId) from [dbo].[Properties]
WHERE 
    [dbo].[Users].Id = [dbo].[Properties].AcquisitionAssociateId 
    and 
    [dbo].[Properties].Stage = 'Purchase') / @PropertyCount)

...Repeat for 3 other stages
```

This method is correctly counting the number of properties in each stage, but after executing it, I realized that what it is actually doing is counting the number of properties that have a user assigned to them, and not getting a distinct count of how many properties an individual user actually has. I'm learning SQL as I go, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do the terms, "properties assigned to user" and "properties user has" actually mean?

Comment: What's RDBMS? It looks like SQL Sever. Please confirm.

Comment: @Dan - What I meant was, each property either has one user, or no users, assigned to it. I'm trying to calculate the total number of properties a user has assigned to them (when UserId in table b is equal to the Id in table a), and then calculate the percentage of properties in each of the four stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a pivot.  The following does the calculation using `avg()`.  It assigns the value of "1" for the stat and the average does the division by the total on the row:

```
select userid,
       avg(case when Stage = 'Inspect' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as InspectStat,
       avg(case when Stage = 'Purchase' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as PurchaseStat,
       avg(case when Stage = 'Sold' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as SoldStat,
       avg(case when Stage = 'POS' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as POSStat
from properties p
group by userid
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the answers i was looking for.